# Sharp Shadows Problem

Tags: shaders, sculpting

I'm fiddling about with a model from Bayonetta 2, learning how to do textures and junk, but when I look at her nose I noticed some ugly bad sadness.
[image: Gross ew bad shading on the nose]

How do I smoothen the shadow out? I haven't noticed this elsewhere on the model. Also, I was having a similar problem on a model I was making from the ground up but for some reason felt compelled to ask about it now.
EDIT: just noticed the same problem on her jaw.

ANSWER: Instead of flipping the normals or whatever, press W in edit mode and press "smooth". It's right underneath the flip normals option.

Comment: Double check the normals of the problematic faces, they might be inverted.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I flipped the normals several times to no avail. However, I noticed a "smooth" option right underneath "flip normals" after pressing W in edit mode. It fixed the strange shadows.

Comment: Great. Please right your own answer. That'll help the next inquirer!